# Increase request timeout in Ember server

Tags: express, ember.js, ember-cli

When using my Ember application in the Ember server ("ember serve"), any request that takes over 1.00 minutes fails with a 502 error.  However, when I build my app, and use my local Apache server, requests don't fail for several minutes.

How do I increase the request timeout in Ember server? I don't see any options anywhere to set this value, nor can I find any sort of documentation online.

Comment: Are you talking about the proxy server? why do you want requests longer then 1 minute?

Comment: I assume it's the proxy server - the server I get when using "ember server" (with port 4200).  I need to let requests take longer than one minute because I'm working with a local REST server that makes database queries to a remote database server, and the latency sometimes makes the requests take a very long time.  (Note, production code runs exponentially faster since REST server and database server are in the same location).

Comment: I assume you mean that part of the server that you run with `ember server --proxy=...`. Right?

Comment: Yes.  My proxy is pointing to my REST server. I had the REST server's address hard-coded in the application adapter as the host. I removed that setting, and used --proxy instead, but the one-minute timeout still happened.

Comment: Wait, this is a different setup. You have the problem if you hard-coded the server address into the application adapter as well? Because then you don't use the ember server for it. Or do you have the problem only when using `--proxy`?

Comment: I have reproduced the problem with both scenarios.  If I do an "ember build", and run the built version on my Apache server, the problem does not exist.

Comment: This doesn't really makes sense. If you make a CORS request the request never hits the ember server. Something is missing here.

Comment: I thought this was being caused by an ember server setting, but @Lux convinced me that is probably wasn't.  So I looked closely at my Apache configuration, and noticed my ProxyPass settings were missing the timeout argument entirely.  Putting a longer timeout there solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this myself.  It wasn't a problem with Ember server after all.  The problem was my ember proxy was pointing to an Apache server, which in-turn proxied the API server. The Apache ProxyPass setting was missing the timeout argument, so it was defaulting to 60 seconds.  I needed to add a timeout to my ProxyPass setting in my `httpd.conf` file, like so:

```
ProxyPass /api https://localhost:8081/api timeout=180
```

Answer (score 0):

The following may help.

As specified here, you can add the `timeout` in `ms` in the hash returned by `ajaxOptions` in the adapter.

https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/how-to-set-ajax-timeout-for-ember-rsvp-or-store-findrecord/8386/4

They have also mentioned the limitation that If

> If Ember stop receiding from Jquery, this will not be an option.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work.  The Ember server always seems to timeout at exactly one minute.  Since I don't have the same problem running the app on my Apache server, I don't think it's related to ajaxOptions anyway.  I suspect it's something to do with the express-server.